Yii2 Editable внутри ActiveForm
Есть у меня компонент
<?php ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['id' => 'productForm']]); ?>
// поля формы

<?php foreach ($goodsInStockList as $point): ?>
<td><?= Editable::widget([
'model' => $point,
'attribute' => 'reservation',
'formOptions' => [
'id' => 'update-reservation' . $point->id . $good->id,
'action' => ['/order/' . $point->stock_id . '/update-reservation/' . $good->id],],
'inputType' => Editable::INPUT_HTML5,
'options' => [
'type' => 'number',
'name' => 'reservation',
'min' => 0,
'disabled' => $model->order_status === Order::STATUS_CONFIRM,
'max' => $point->count,
'class' => 'form-control',
'placeholder' => 'Введите число для резерва',
'id' => 'reservation-' . $good->id . $point->id,
],
                                                                                                            ]); ?></td>
<?php endforeach; ?>
// остальные поля формы
<?php ActiveForm:end() ?>


Проблема такая - в цикле первый Editable создается без обертки <form с id 'update-reservation' . $point[0]->id . $good[0]->id
при этом Jquery код для этой формы создается
var $el=jQuery("#update-reservation17117 .kv-hint-special");if($el.length){$el.each(function(){$(this).activeFieldHint()});}
jQuery('#update-reservation17117').yiiActiveForm([], []);

Но самой формы нет.
Если я выпиливаю
<?php ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['id' => 'productForm']]); ?>

то все ок. Соответственно проблема в том что Editable видит что какая-та форма создана уже и не создает новую.

Так как Вы не привели в коде чей же Editable Вы подключаете, предположу, что kartik-овский. Если это так, то достаточно открыть файл Editable.php в vendor\kartik-v\yii2-editable чтобы увидеть в коде:
 /**
     * Initializes the widget
     */
    protected function initEditable()
    {
        ...   
        //Вот тут `kartik` требует чтобы был указан `formClass` (по-умолчанию это `\kartik\form\ActiveForm`)
        if (!empty($this->formClass) && !class_exists($this->formClass)) {
            throw new InvalidConfigException("The form class '{$this->formClass}' does not exist.");
        }
        /**
         * @var string|ActiveForm $class
         */
        $class = $this->formClass;
        if (!class_exists($class)) {
            throw new InvalidConfigException("The form class '{$class}' set via 'Editable::formClass' does not exist.");
        }
        //А вот тут `kartik` сам создает ActiveForm
        $this->_form = $class::begin($this->formOptions);

        if (!$this->_form instanceof ActiveForm) {
            throw new InvalidConfigException("The form class '{$class}' MUST extend from '\yii\widgets\ActiveForm'.");
        }
    }

Таким образом, все, что Вам нужно - это передать в настройках Editable в параметре formClass - название класса Вашей формы и дальше Editable все сделает за Вас.
Более подробно можете почитать в описании виджета на странице проекта

Не совсем понимаю чем может помочь добавление formClass к виджету.
Не уверен что вы верно поняли суть проблемы, мне не нужно привязать виджет к ActiveForm.
Мне бы наоборот хотелось чтобы каждый виджет внутри цикла был обернут в свою собственную форму, что и происходит со всеми виджетами созданными в цикле кроме первого.
Если посмотреть на то что вы приложили то виджет не требует указания formClass, а требует чтобы класс был, если параметр formClass не пустой.

Вам нужно убрать свое создание формы. В виджет либо передайте класс формы который Вам нужен, либо не передавайте - тогда виджет сам его присвоит классу формы от kartik. После чего САМ создаст форму и выведет в нее виджет. Уберите ActiveForm::begin, ActiveForm:end() оставьте только вывод виджета в цикле

Я же говорю. Вы неверно поняли суть. Возможно я плохо объяснил. Мне не нужно убирать ActiveForm::begin/end
Форма выше нужна для других полей.
Грубо говоря - мне нужно чтобы внутри  формы были формы (созданные Editable)
Но я решил проблему добавив перед циклом скрытый Editable виджет.
